# Unable to import PyODBC in AWS Lambda for MS Sql Server

Tags: python, sql-server, lambda, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I want to connect to MS SQL Server using `pyodbc` on AWS Lambda.
When i deploy the package, i get an error:

```
No module named "pyodbc".
```

I have added the following files in the Lambda package:

- pyodbc.cp36-win32
- pyodbc-4.0.16.dist-info
- dbaccess.py

`dbaccess.py` contains the working code with pyodbc.

What am I missing to deploy `pyodbc` on AWS Lambda so I can connect to SQL Server?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64327675/2506172

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides a guide on how to build packages for deployment here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

The being said, you can short-cut the process for pyodbc for Lambda here: https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages/pyodbc